# Create a custom list on Storyboard Xcode

Tags: xcode, list, user-interface, storyboard, user-experience

Being a beginner with Xcode, I wanted to know if it was possible to create a list with our own components? I explain, it would be to make a list of favorites scrolling on an Xcode view, with an image, a button to delete it, and a text. It is obvious that I will have to create more components but how to put them in a list without limits?
The prototype design is as follows:
[Here !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOjW7.png)

Thank you in advance, Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make your own list cells. For that you will need to,

1. create your own `UITableViewCell` and add your componenents (2x UIImageViews, 1x UILabel)
2. register your cell to the `UITableView` you want to display the cell in with the `identifier`
3. Conform to both `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource`

Refer [this blog](https://programmingwithswift.com/create-a-custom-uitableviewcell-with-swift/) to learn more as I barely scratched the surface with the explanation

You can add data to the table as follows

```
/// Conforming to the UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource protocols
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Table view to display data
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // setting the datasource and delegate
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }

    /// 2d Array to store data
    let data = [["Melon", "Glace"], ["Epinard"], ["one", "two", "three"] ]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }

    /// UITableViewDataSource protocol stubs
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as? CustomTableViewCell {
            cell.name = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer,but when I followed your tutorial, it does not indicate how to add your cell to the list... Did you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my answer to make more sense